# Unknown interference between signal generator, oscilloscope, and op-amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, oscilloscope, probe, signal-generator

[image]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9ETAH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am new to hardware experiments, although I have acceptable theoretical knowledge. My setup is:

- a signal generator
- a breadboard with an op-amp (not powered)
- an oscilloscope

The output of the generator has a splitter, one cable goes directly to the oscilloscope plotting the input (a sine wave). The second cable leaving the splitter is a crocodile clip cable. The oscilloscope has a probe.

There is this phenomenon I don't understand. When neither the probe nor the crocodile cable are attached to anything the sine wave shows correctly on the oscilloscope (I am just talking about the direct line from the generator, not the probe). When I connect the ground of the oscilloscope probe to the Vcc- of the op-amp, and the red crocodile cable to the IN+ of the op-amp, the sine wave is distorted (see photo attached).

I am sure there must be a simple answer, maybe something to do with the device impedance etc. but I just can't wrap my head around it. This prevents me from properly measuring the op-amp's output for an input sine wave.

[image]

The following schematic shows the fully connected setup. The input sine wave is still distorted, however the op amp works fine (don't have a photo, but it's constant high value when input is positive and constant low when negative)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4a8d3.png)</sup>

Comment: Where are the attached photos? What is the period and amplitude of the sine wave shown on the oscilloscope? What are the settings of the signal generator? Influence of selecting different waveforms?

Comment: You don't mention what kind of opamp it is. See if you can find a datasheet that shows its internal schematic, and try to work out how the inputs might behave if the opamp has no power.

Comment: Are you really connecting this to an *unpowered* op-amp?  In that case you might be powering the op amp via the input (+ scope ground), hence the distortion.  (This would depend on the op-amp, but don't assume *any* behaviour for powered-down active components unless stated: all kinds of fun things can happen (as different parts of the chip cross conduction thresholds, draw too much power and turn off again, causing oscillation, etc).  You've effectively created a severe brown-out situation.

Comment: Please *edit your question* by including a schematic of the circuit.  If you _absolutely don't know how to make a schematic_ then a picture of the board or a muntzing diagram, along with a statement that you can't make schematics, is -- OK.  And -- what @2e0byo said about trying to inject a signal into a powered-down op-amp.

Comment: Lacking a drawing showing the exact setup, let me venture a guess that the OP has neglected the fact that the ground of the oscilloscope probe, and the ground of the signal generator output, are connected via the mains ground.

Comment: @2e0byo That is a valid point, indeed being the same ground, the sine wave is injected in the IN+ and IN- is connected to the ground, so that might mean the opamp is "powered through the input", which I am not sure what effect it has, but still doesn't explain why the direct line from the generator to the oscilloscope is affected, which (theoretically) shouldn't change depending on where I inject the generated input.

Comment: @Uwe I can't remember by heart but I can see from the scope pic the period was 200ms. The amplitude was 40V. When I change to square wave you can't see the effect, but that is piecewise constant so it doesn't surprise me.

Comment: @sh- That's a good point but as explained to 2e0 above this still doesn't solve the dilemma.

Comment: @TimWescott I do apologise I don't know the symbols for everything so the schematic would probably not be helpful. But the setup is the simplest I can imagine: direct line between the signal generator and oscilloscope displaying the input (which in my intuition should not change depending on where I inject that signal; this intuition is clearly proven wrong). Then the signal is injected into the opamp IN+ and IN-. The opamp is unpowered, but apparently you can power it through the input. Lastly the oscilloscope probe ground is connected to the Vcc-. That's it.

Comment: @TimWescott I verified the datasheet of the IC, that's how I know what pins to choose and how to power it. But then again this does not explain why what I do downstream changes what happens upstream.

I am not in the lab anymore, but I will take more photos next time if it helps.

Comment: I don't believe the period is 200 ms, it is 20 ms and the frequency is 50 Hz. It is not a generator signal, it is a pick up of the mains voltage from the power grid.

Comment: @Uwe I don't know if I'm reading the period wrong from the pic, but it's not from the power grid. Unless the power grid looks like a square wave when I change the input type.

Comment: What is the frequency setting of the generator? What happens if you change the generator frequency?

Comment: You definitely can affect a direct line between scope and generator by a circuit attached yo the generator: you just need to draw enough current (or inject enough)--which might not be much if your generator is in high z mode.  But fwiw my money is on a ground issue.  Schematic and it should be clearer.

Comment: I added a schematic (to the best of my ability), plus a photo of the hardware setup. I confirm the frequency of the signal is 5 Hz, the reading I initially made from the scope display was correct (the period is approximately 200ms), so this has nothing to do with the power grid. Additionally, when I fully hook up the op amp the output is as expected, piecewise constant, with the high value when the waveform is positive. However, the input waveform is still distorted and my initial dilemma is still going on. Changing the input frequency doesn't fix it (went up to 500Hz)

Comment: @Uwe The frequency is 5Hz. Ramping it up to up to 500Hz doesn't fix it, upon zooming in on the high frequency waveform it looks the same.

Comment: @2e0byo I added the schematic. I don't know how to change (or if i can change) the impedance of the signal generator, but that shouldn't distort but more like scale the input right?

Comment: @TimWescott the post was updated thanks

Comment: @DaveTweed The pins that trigger the phenomenon are the Vcc- pin of the opamp (connected to ground of the probe) and the IN+ pin (connected to the + of the alligator clip). The schematic is attached (hope it's understandable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was indeed a grounding issue. The closest answer came from @2e0by0. As the schematic shows, I was connecting the Vcc- pin to ground. Now I am using two power sources in series, so I have Vcc -Vcc and ground. The input is fed into the amp using ground as reference. The signal distortion is not present anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Signal generators like that have a finite output impedance -- usually 50 ohms.

You're putting a signal into an unpowered amplifier.  Unless a chip is specially designed for that purpose, applying a voltage to an unpowered chip will make it conduct.  *Probably* what is happening is that the positive-going  swing is powering the op-amp through various parasitic diodes, while the negative-going swing is just turning a diode on -- hence the asymmetrical response.

In general, you need to observe the device's absolute maximum ratings, which almost invariably call for not applying input voltages outside of the bounds of the positive and negative supplies.

In specific, in this case, you should build an op-amp circuit of some sort (the chip by itself is not a useful amplifier; just the core of one).  Then you should *power it up* and see how things work.

Comment: Just to quote what I said in one of the comments (there were quite a lot) "Additionally, when I fully hook up the op amp the output is as expected, piecewise constant, with the high value when the waveform is positive." When fully operational the amp does its job however the input still looks the same (distorted). Trying to change parameters doesn't work. The only thing that fixes it is adding a bias to the input, putting it in positive territory. So something is happening when it goes negative...

Comment: That picture shows just two wires going to the op-amp -- that's not a fully operational amp.  Perhaps you could show a picture of _the actual setup_ then.

Comment: With a closeup of how the opamp is connected on the board -- if you'd had an actual circuit in that shot I wouldn't have been able to make out the details.

Comment: Is there a way I can add two schematics? I don't have a photo with the whole circuit and I don't want to confuse by suddenly changing the diagram

Comment: I _think_ so -- just put your cursor somewhere and push the "schematic" button.

Comment: Thanks I added a new schematic at the end.

Comment: Something I noticed is that when I add a feedback with a capacitor on (to make it an integrator) the distortion is gone and the input looks like a clean sine wave.